# Javascript match text between code

Tags: javascript, preg-match, between

I want to get the exact script function from html body with preg_match in javascript;

I try but not working:

```
var whatineed=jQuery('html').html().match('$j('#send_form').submit(function(e) {(.*?)return true;');alert(whatineed);
```

Please help, I need to get precisely this part:

```
$j.cookie('77fd78cdfc6b67274cf648bdf9f2d0b7', '60c6083d29b6a29d11068fecee75ab99', {path: '/'});
```

From bodies of this type with javascript:

```
<html><body><script language="JavaScript">
$j('#send_form').submit(function(e) {
    $j.cookie('77fd78cdfc6b67274cf648bdf9f2d0b7', '60c6083d29b6a29d11068fecee75ab99', {path: '/'});
    return true;
});
</script></body></html>
```

Comment: THere're no `preg_match` in [javascript].

Answer (score 0):

Is that exactly the JavaScript you're running? You have a problem with your quotation marks...

```
var whatineed=jQuery('html').html().match('$j(\'#send_form\').submit(function(e) {(.*?)return true;');alert(whatineed);
```

Comment: I guess that's why it's not working, so I'm asking for help with a similar but сorrect solution.